# How can I convert an image to a base64 format which is stored in my project folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I convert an image to a base64 format which is stored in my project folder? I have tried this. But it doesn't work

```
     public string ImageToBase64( string path)
    {
        string path = @"~/img/company.png";
        using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path))
        {
            using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `path = Server.MapPath(path)`.  Also note that you're currently overwriting the path parameter (I assume that's deliberate for this post, but pointing out in case accidental).

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What do you mean it with `it doesn't work`? Do you get any errors?

Comment: You know `doesn't work` just doesn't work, you need to specify 3 things to get an answer: what you did, what you get, what you expected

Comment: @FaizanRabbani this is the error.. Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: D:\AbdulPC\mvc sample\eVitalz-mvc-version-69\eVitalz-mvc\Home\~img\company.png

Comment: @FaizanRabbani .. but sir . It is there in my project.  Sir "eVitalz-mvc" is my project folder. The image is in the Folder "img".  Shall I change the path to "~/eVitalz-mvc/img/company.png";

Comment: See This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21325753/7738489

Comment: @JohnLBevan . Thank you sir. Now it works.

Comment: @Abdu no worries, I've given a slightly more detailed answer below to explain why this works; hopefully it makes sense / aids your understanding.  Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path)` resolve the path from a URL to an absolute path.  You can do this by calling `Server.MapPath(path)`.

i.e.

```
string path = @"~/img/company.png";
path = Server.MapPath(path);
using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path))
```

or simply

```
string path = @"~/img/company.png";
using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(path)))
```

**More Detailed Explanation**

- When dealing with resources on the web, we use URLs.
- The URL `~/img/company.png` says to navigate from the site's root (this is what the tilde (`~`) refers to) to the `img` subfolder, then to the file `company.png`.
- The `System.Drawing.Image` class was not built for URLs, so doesn't know how to handle them.  Rather it expects a path for the file system.  The reasons it can't understand a URL are:

  - it doesn't know what tilde means
  - it doesn't know where the site's root is
  - even given `path = @"img\company.png"` it would try to find the file based on the working directory rather than the site's root directory.  The current working directory is likely to be the location of IIS's executable ([c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485195/webclient-download-access-to-the-path-c-windows-system32-inetsrv-myprin/16485227#16485227) though I'm not sure / it's probably best not to know as the idea of a working directory doesn't make sense in a web context).
  - it has no awareness of virtual paths; so even if the working directory were the same as the site's root and the tilde were missed, `\img\` may sit in an entirely different location on disk to where it comes in the site's structure; perhaps even being mapped to a share on some remote file server).
- Calling `Server.MapPath` resolves this URL to a real path which can be understood by non-web aware functions.

There's a great answer giving a lot more detail and examples on `Server.MapPath` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27500722/361842